# Spring Data and Cassandra @Query with variable table names

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Spring Cassandra entity class as follows:

```
@Builder
@Table(value = "#{@environment.getProperty('my.table.name')}")
public class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String id;
  // Other fields defined
}
```

This is my configuration

```
my.table.name: User
```

Here, "my.table.name" is being passed from my config [equivalent to a @Value] file using SpEL support. This works as expected.

Now, the problem is with my Repository class.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<UserEntity, String> {
    @Query("UPDATE User SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = ?0")
    Flux<UserEntity> incrementCount(String id);
}
```

Here I am unable to find an expression [SpEL] to replace the table name "User" in @Query with a variable [a configuration such as @Value]. Is there a possibility to get this done?